# How to decrypt a read-only encrypted chromebook wifi password on Chrome os (linux)

Tags: linux, bash, encryption, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I would like to decrypt a wifi password that my chromebook has been registered to. The encrypted code is: CbD4Fb4o=:7_C?:4oE:_?>b

For some reason, when I run the linux/chrome shell command to decrypt it using `echo`, it tells me that the encryption is read only. If I delete the `>b` which I believe is setting the file to be read-only, the decrypted code results in r3scu3c@lif0rnic@ti0n which is not the proper code.

Here is the command that I have tried to run:

```
echo CbD4Fb4o=:7_C?:4oE:_?>b |tr '!-~' 'P-~!-O'
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me out.

Comment: Quote your encrypted string `echo "CbD4Fb4o=:7_C?:4oE:_?>b" |tr '!-~' 'P-~!-O'`. That `>b` is being interpreted as a redirect otherwise and the pipe then doesn't make much sense.